# How do I add a js file to react ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I have a function that works great in the react js project, but I need to add it to the react ts project. How to reuse this component?

JS file

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, Stage, PresentationControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import bmw from './res/bmw.glb'

function Model(props) {
  const {scene} = useGLTF('/res/bmw.glb');
  console.log('scene', scene)
  return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />
}

export function Object3D() {
  return (
    <Canvas dpr={[1, 2]} shadows camera={{ fov: 45 }} style={{"position": "absolute"}}>
      <color attach="background" args={["#1010101"]} />
      <PresentationControls speed={1.5} global zoom={.5} polar={[-0.1, Math.PI / 4]}>
        <Stage environment={null}> 
          <Model scale={0.01} />
        </Stage>
      </PresentationControls>
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

Error: index.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useId is not a function
at useFiber